# How can I use `jest-dynamodb` in a `nx` managed monorepo?

Tags: node.js, jestjs, amazon-dynamodb, ts-jest

I have a monorepo managed by `nx`. Each package in this repo references the jest config file from repo root directory. I need to use `@shelf/jest-dynamodb` to support running dynamodb local for test cases. (https://github.com/shelfio/jest-dynamodb)

One of the package is under `packages/is-even/jest.config.js` like below:

```
import path from 'path';

/* eslint-disable */
process.env.JEST_DYNAMODB_CONFIG = path.resolve(__dirname, './jest-dynamodb-config');

console.log('JEST_DYNAMODB_CONFIG:', process.env.JEST_DYNAMODB_CONFIG);

export default {
  displayName: 'is-even',
  preset: '../../jest.preset.js',
};
```

the root level `jest.preset.js` is:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@shelf/jest-dynamodb',
  testMatch: ['**/?(*.)+(spec|test).[jt]s?(x)'],
  resolver: '@nx/jest/plugins/resolver',
  moduleFileExtensions: ['ts', 'js'],
  transform: { '^.+\\.(ts|js|html)$': ['ts-jest', [Object]] },
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testEnvironmentOptions: { customExportConditions: ['node', 'require', 'default'] },
  testTimeout: 5000,
```

when running the test case, the local dynamodb instance is not launched. Is there a way to make it work with monorepo?